# Alexa skill works only for "launch request" intent

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've created the lambda function for Alexa skill. All the intents and questions are working fine when tested in amazon developer console. When same is deployed in Alexa App, only launch request intent is working well, other intents are failing to give exact output. Code sample [here](https://gist.github.com/srinivasyl/44dbe30f05df94d1a10f92b9e90043ee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Lambda log (CloudWatch), then try adding console.log() messages to see if your methods are being called, and if so what is happening.

I've seen similar problems in code when it was expecting upper case strings. Alexa always passes strings in lower case. For example, you can type "Hello" into the console and if the code is comparing with "Hello" it will work. But when you speak "Hello" to Alexa, it will pass the string "hello" (all lower case) in the request.